# Prove that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha + n}{\beta + n} $ equals $1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'd like to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha + n}{\beta + n} = 1$$

I've worked out that $$\frac{|\alpha - \beta|}{|\beta + n|} < \epsilon$$ if $n < N$ for integers $n$ and $N$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: What is this sequence $s_n$ you are referring to, and how is that related? (I.e. are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constants?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\alpha = \beta$ it is obvious. Otherwise, fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and look for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\Big|\frac{\alpha+n}{\beta+n}-1\Big| < \varepsilon \text{ when } n > N. $$
You find immediately
$$\Big|\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta+n} \Big| < \varepsilon \rightarrow  \frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{\varepsilon} < |\beta+n| \leq |\beta|+n$$
So if you set $N > \frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{\varepsilon}-|\beta|$ you get the result.

Comment: A fantastic and concise explanation, thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Glad that this helps.

Answer (score 9):

write $$\frac{\frac{\alpha}{n}+1}{\frac{\beta}{n}+1}$$ and this tends to $1$ for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question--I forgot to include the absolute value bars. Please let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: @Taliant It does not

Comment: I was immediately worried about what impact different $\alpha$ and $\beta$ values would have. I'm glad your answer reminds me about one of the simple limit rules!

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{\alpha + n}{\beta + n} = \frac{\alpha - \beta + \beta + n}{\beta + n}\\
= \frac{\alpha - \beta}{\beta + n} + \frac{\beta + n}{\beta + n}\\
= \frac{\alpha - \beta}{\beta + n} + 1
$$
so by definition $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\alpha + n}{\beta + n} = 1$ means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in \Bbb N$ such that as long as $n>N$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{\alpha + n}{\beta + n} - 1\right|<\epsilon
$$
However, by the above argument, this is inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{\beta + n}\right|<\epsilon
$$
and you already know that there is an $N$ that works in this case. So we're done.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question--I forgot to include the absolute value bars. Please let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: @Taliant Not at all (once you see that $\frac{|\alpha - \beta|}{|\beta + n|}$ and $\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{\beta + n}\right|$ are the same). In fact, that's what I've actually used in my answer, so if anything you've made it clearer how to put the two together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish

$$|\alpha-\beta|<|\beta+n|\epsilon.$$

This is obviously obtained with

$$n>\frac{|\alpha-\beta|}\epsilon-\beta,$$ where the RHS is a well-defined finite number.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\left|\frac{\alpha+n}{\beta+n}-1\right|
= \left|\frac{\alpha+n-\beta-n}{\beta+n}\right|
= \left|\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\beta+n}\right|
= \frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{|\beta+n|}
$$

You showed that the right side is finally $<\epsilon$ for large enough $n$. This means that the left side will too. And this is *the definition* of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha+n}{\beta+n}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha=\beta$ it's trivial if not you can divide by $|\alpha-\beta|$ to get
$$\frac1{|\beta+n|} <\frac\epsilon{|\alpha-\beta|} $$
Now take the greatest integer smaller or equal to $\beta+n$ denote it by $[\beta+n] $ then $\frac1{|\beta+n|} <\frac1{[|\beta+n|]} <\frac\epsilon{|\alpha-\beta|} $ the last inequality is due the Archimedian property.